# ORA-00922 When trying to place table in memory

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, in-memory-database

I've two environments, Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit, which are basically identical.
In one I could successfully place the tables I wanted in memory, but in the other one I get 'ORA-00922: missing or invalid option'.
The command I'm executing is

```
ALTER TABLE USER_ROLE_T INMEMORY PRIORITY MEDIUM;
```

Both environments are configured with INMEMORY parameter and SGA_TARGET is configured to '0'.

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused due to incorrect parameter value.
The COMPATIBLE parameter was set to Oracle 11.2.4, as the server was upgraded to Oracle 12c from Oracle 11g.
Once I've set the parameter to the correct Oracle version, the issue was resolved.